# How to get current theme name in Magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento i am trying to get current theme or package name but not found anything.
I used getSkinUrl(') but it's return skin path not package or theme name.please help me how i can get theme or package name.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Current Package**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName()
```

**Current Theme (frontend)**

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend')
```

Comment: Like @peter-a points out in his answer, 'frontend' is not one of the possible options for `getTheme()`. Use 'locale', 'layout', 'template', 'default' or 'skin'. Otherwise `getTheme()` will always return 'default'.

Answer (score 13):

Please note that the above answer by @Drew Hunter is not entirely correct. While `getTheme()` is the desired function call, the string 'frontend' is not an accepted parameter for this method. The only allowed values for this method are:

- locale
- layout
- template
- default
- skin

That is to say, the correct usage of this function is one of the following lines:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme()
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('locale')
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('layout')
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('template')
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('default')
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('skin')
```

Failing to use the method in this manner will **always** return the string 'default'.

**Unexpected Results**

Incorrect usage will produce logic errors. An example of this is if you have a 'Matched Expression' defined to specifically target mobile devices.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
```

references the following class

```
Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package
```

By looking at the 'getTheme()' method in this class you will notice possible options you can pass this method, they are 'locale', 'layout', 'template', 'default' and 'skin'.

Therefore, if a particular store had 'Matched Expression' for 'template' like the following

```
iPhone|iPod|Mobile|mobile > mobile
```

The following may happen

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend') RETURNS 'default'
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('template') RETURNS 'mobile'
```

Answer (score 9):

Since

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')
```

is equivalent of

```
Mage::getDesign()
```

Drew's examples can be shorten to:

```
Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName()
```

and

```
Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('frontend')
```

Answer (score 1):

here the another way:

```
$package = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/package/name');
$skin_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/theme/skin');
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add this as comment, but you can also get it straight from the database with

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path="design/theme/skin";
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path="design/package/name";
```

That's probably more useful for admins than in use live, you should use the magento functions if you're designing a template or coding within magento.