# How to get active theme name in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I was working on a Magento site and couldn't find a way to get the current active theme information. Please suggest a way to get current active theme information on Magento platform. I am using Magento version 1.7.0.2

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this information programmatically see [How to get current theme name in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155570/how-to-get-current-theme-name-in-magento)

```
  Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName()
  Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend')
```

From the admin

```
Admin -> System -> Config -> General -> Design -> Themes
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please tell the difference between a Package and a Theme in Magento. Thanks!

Comment: Package is a set of variations of a theme. Inside a package and theme name {some_package_name}/{some_theme_name}, if some files are missing in that folder, they will fallback first to the {some_package_name}/default theme, so to the file in the latter directory. If there is no template file there either, Magento falls back (takes the template) from base/default directory.

Answer (score 3):

From the admin Dashboard, look at System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes

This will correspond to a directory in app/design/frontend/default/[theme name] directory.