# Magento - determine which theme a customer used when placing an order?

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento EE 1.9 website running two different themes for the same store: one for desktop and the other for mobile. The theme is changed based on user-agent using the design exception string under System -> Design -> Theme.

All I want to do is to see which orders came from the desktop theme and which orders came from the mobile theme, so I can determine if an order came from the desktop site or the mobile site.

Is there a way to save the name of the theme as a custom attribute or flag when an order is placed?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd create a Magento extension with event observer inside, and would listen to event and there you can update your order attribute or generate your feed, so it's up to you

> sales_order_place_after

Then it depends how you developed your mobile theme in order to find it's name:

This should return the name of the theme

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('frontend')
```

But according to [this SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155570/how-to-get-current-theme-name-in-magento)

if you use 'Matched Expression' for 'template' you should better try

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getTheme('template')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I know how to get the name of the theme but I don't know where to save it. Can I just do something like `$order->setMyCustomAttributeHere("myValue");`? Or do I have to define `myCustomAttribute` somewhere before I do that?

Comment: can be done as an attriute, why not? read this, hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936470/adding-a-new-attribute-to-order-in-magento